# `redis-cli monitor` this command does not get ip and port,why?

Tags: redis

In redis document, I found that  the result of `redis-cli monitor` command is below:

```
$ redis-cli monitor
1339518083.107412 [0 127.0.0.1:60866] "keys" "*"
1339518087.877697 [0 127.0.0.1:60866] "dbsize"
1339518090.420270 [0 127.0.0.1:60866] "set" "x" "6"
```

But when I type this command, I get this result:

```
$ redis-cli monitor
1339518083.107412 "keys" "*"
1339518087.877697 "dbsize"
1339518090.420270 "set" "x" "6"
```

[0 127.0.0.1:60866] is gone. Why?
My redis version is 2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Printing the server's IP and port in `MONITOR`'s output had been added in [this](https://github.com/antirez/redis/commit/e31b615e6201fccda3f2e036c449646e3cfbac25) commit that's part of version 2.6. Version 2.2 does not include this information.